# `Meteor.call` - Invoking server method from server code?

Tags: meteor, methods, server

From Meteor docs I know that:

> `Meteor.call` can be [used anywhere](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_call)

In which cases would you use `Meteor.call` from the server over directly calling a method from another module/class/object?

```
=== server/file.js ===
let myPromise = Meteor.callAsync('aServerMethod', options);
```

vs

```
=== server/file.js ===
let myPromise = aModule.aMethod(options);
```

Comment: there is not a question here?

Comment: @corvid Fixed. Added missing question mark.

Comment: Go ask your questions in SO [they said](https://forums.meteor.com/t/why-no-stack-overflow/20158), it's a very active community they said....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One key difference would be that inside a `Meteor.method`, `this` is bound to the method invocation object, which provides a bunch of stuff like `this.userId` or `this.unblock`, see [docs for more](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_methods). You don't get this in regular functions.

Another one is, that all methods are callable from the client, as I'm sure you know. So if you want to do server-only stuff, I would not use a `Meteor.method` but a regular function instead. If I want to expose the `serverMethod` also to the client, I'd use a `Meteor.method`.